# Object.entries() does return an empty array for Maps

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just found, that calling `Object.entries` on a Map does return an empty array.
I would expect it to return whatever is returned by `Map.entries()`.

Example:

```
let map = new Map([[1, 2]])
map.entries() // [[1, 2]]
Object.entries(map) // []
```

Is there a reason for this behavior?
I want to convert inputs to maps but want to allow both, objects and maps. So I went:

```
let map = new Map(Object.entries(input))
```

But that doesnt work because `Object.entries` does not work for Maps.

Is there any solution for this? Or can this be enhanced? Are there plans to "fix" this?

Comment: Actually `Map.entries()` returns an iterator.

Comment: Why not use `map.entries()`? Is there any specific use-case which prevents you from doing so?

Comment: @31piy as explained I have an `input` which can be an object OR a map. I want to get a map out of this input in a neat way

Comment: You can try something like `Array.from(map instanceof Map ? map.entries() : Object.entries(map))`.